# urlseek.vmn.net problem

Tags: windows, redirection, anti-virus, hijack

Whenever i try to open some websites it suddenly redirects me to links like these

http://urlseek60.vmn.net/search.php?tbn=panda2_0dn&type=404&v=10062&q=www.pandatech.vn/forum/viewtopic.php?f=24&p=2056
http://urlseek60.vmn.net/search.php?tbn=panda2_0dn&type=dns&v=10062&q=www.onlive.com
http://urlseek60.vmn.net/search.php?tbn=panda2_0dn&type=404&v=10062&q=game.stackexchange.com

It happens on a few links, many other websites open well. I think panda cloud antivirus and its toolbar are somewhat involved in this issue.
I un-installed toolbar but no effect, then i stopped panda and no now more redirections.

Comment: What browser is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises from Panda toolbar as you stated, but it is strange that uninstalling the toolbar didn't solve the problem. Did you restart your PC after uninstallation? Please try this first. If you are sure you properly uninstalled the toolbar, then you can try the method suggested on this [thread](http://forums.techguy.org/virus-other-malware-removal/932673-http-urlseek-vmn-net-keeps.html). A program called ComboFix is suggested and it seems to solve the problem. Good luck.